# Bad IL format - Strange .NET error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm getting this error message randomly through my .NET application in Azure.

There seems to be very limited information available on the error, and I wondered if anyone knew what may be causing it?

It seems to occur when a certain stored procedure is called, but its really difficult to re-create and happens randomly.

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL format.
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateAndReconnect(Action beforeDisconnect, Int32 timeout)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery(AsyncCallback callback, Object stateObject)
 at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncImpl(Func`3 beginMethod, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Chances are this is because of a processor architecture mismatch: loading 64-bit assemblies when you use 32-bit causes this, for instance.

Some things to check:

> - If your application uses 32-bit components, make sure that it always runs as a 32-bit application.
> - Make sure that you are not using a component that was created with a different version of the .NET Framework.
> - Make sure that the file image is a valid managed assembly or module.

And, as far as the first item on the list goes:

> If the **Platform target** property for your application project is set to **AnyCPU**, the compiled application can be run in either 64-bit or 32-bit mode. When it runs as a 64-bit application, the just-in-time (JIT) compiler produces 64-bit native code. If the application depends on a 32-bit managed or unmanaged component, that component will fail to load in 64-bit mode. To correct this problem, set the project's **Platform target** property to **x86** and recompile.

Source: [Troubleshooting Exceptions: System.BadImageFormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7137bfe.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Rick, appreciate that prompt answer. I've made these changes and will monitor accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Also if you are trying to load .exe generated by netcore 3.1 and obtain still :
System.BadImageFormatException: 'Bad IL format.'

even if you double checked x64 uniformity between loader and target ... you can try to load the associated .dll !

In my case it continued to failed at loading my console app.exe , but didnot  complained to load the dll, which visual studio generates for you !

In fact the .exe is not MSIL , it looks to be a boot loader of the MSIL code in the .dll